# Is a node participating in the ACK process when CAN uses multicasting?

Tags: can-bus

The CAN standard `ISO 11898-1` states that all nodes (aka CAN shield) in a network will send a dominant `ACK bit` at the specific position during the node transmitting a frame to indicate the consistency of the frame w.r.t to the CRC. An unacknowledged frame is seen as corrupted.

At the same time the standard states to be `multicasting` (sending to multiple nodes in the network). Hardware-wise I only perceived `broadcasting` (it is sending to all nodes in the network), which is a subset of multicasting: the filtering of messages occurs not in the nodes itself but on the software of the device connected to its CAN shield interface.

If I have `two nodes` on my bus and `device B` is filtering for an identifier, while `device A` is transmitting a frame with another identifier. Will the frame be acknowledged by `device B`?

From my understanding it should, but I was not able to test this and would like to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, since it was indicated in ISO 11898-1 8.3.1 that the "frame acceptance filtering" is provided at the LLC sub-layer, and the "acknowledgement" is provided at the MAC sub-layer, the "acknowledgement" process will be completed before the "frame acceptance filtering".
So all nodes on the bus will participate in the ACK process even some nodes are filtering for this identifier.

Comment: I see, you refer to this:  Each receiver
shall decide by frame acceptance filtering whether the frame is relevant or not

in 8.3.1 I couldn't find details, as I have the standard of 2015

Answer (score 0):

In CAN properties it states

- all **frame transfer** is done as `broadcast`
- `multicast` frame transfer by **acceptance filtering**

Therefore, as **all** (active) **nodes** are **receiving all frames**, two nodes are sufficient to acknowledge a message with an identifier `device B` filters out.

Comment: Note that acceptance mask filtering is old technology by now. Modern CAN controllers use mailboxes instead, which are dedicated buffers for transmitting/receiving a frame with one particular identifier. Filtering was always problematic since it could only be used effectively on very simple nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I am afraid that I cannot use these mailboxes, as I am limited to CAN 2.0B by hardware.

Comment: The CAN spec has nothing to do with it. This is all about how modern the CAN controller design is. For classic CAN there's basically been 3 generations: external CAN controllers (around year 1995-2000), internal CAN controllers with acceptance filtering (> year 2000), internal CAN controllers with mailbox and DMA etc (>year 2010).

Comment: Interesting! Thank you, I will definitely have a look into that!

Comment: And well... since the question mentions "CAN shield", note that Arduino is using the antique first generation of controllers, due to the fact that Arduino Uno uses a similarly antique MCU from the 1990s. The term "CAN shield" if used properly actually refers to a signal, namely the optinal cable shield in a CAN bus.

Comment: The Pi I use that shield with is is just a test environment before implementing it somewhere else. I will look into that `other devices` capability. However, I needed a `CAN interface` to connect to that `other device`, which is unfortunately not better than that Pi CAN shield.

Comment: hey @[Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) do you have a good source for the different CAN controller generations?

Comment: Not really, I just know from experience since I've worked to and fro with CAN for almost 20 years. The general first stop/source of canonical content is the non-profit organization [CAN in Automation](https://www.can-cia.org/) which maintains the CANopen standards among other things. There's some info about old and new transceivers at their site https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/systemdesign-can-physicallayer/.

Comment: ("Fault tolerant CAN" is mostly obsolete by now, an old high-integrity hardware standard. "High speed CAN" is the classic CAN. CAN FD is the flexible data rate version with higher payload capacity. CAN XL is some work in progress that nobody knows if it will succeed on the market or not. There was an attempt of something similar called "FlexRay" prior CAN FD, but FlexRay became a fiasco and CAN FD pretty much replaced it.)

Comment: Thank you, I assumed so and appreciate you share your experience a lot! I spend yesterday evening trying to find a source because I like how you sum this up, but from what I understand there is no direct relation between the three options you described and CBFF/CEFF, FBFF/FEFF and CAN XL The source suggests otherwise. This is good, this means I can elaborate on that. Thanks again